# Why is a TT national champion not allowed to wear his jersey in TTT

Tags: time-trial

According this source, Wout Van Aert is not allowed to wear his new TT belgian champion jersey in TTT of the tour the france.

I can remember days where this was allowed. Why and when did this change?

[Source](https://sporza.be/nl/2019/06/28/van-aert-driekleur/)

Comment: Why? Because all the good rules have already been made and it was a choice between that and banning leg-shaving. It turns out that Bic have good lobbyists.

Comment: I see you have a great knowledge of the UCI work. Thanks for that input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [rule 1.3.068](https://www.uci.org/docs/default-source/rules-and-regulations/1-gen-20190625-e.pdf?sfvrsn=b6f5c2e4_86) of the UCI regulations: "The national champion in the individual time trial is not authorised to wear the distinctive national champion’s jersey during team time trial events."

I do not know when this particular rule was passed but it does not appear to have happened in 2019 so it must have been earlier.

Comment: I sure it was earlier. But I just noticed it, there used to be teams in the tour TTT where 3-4 riders wore the national jersey.

Answer (score 4):

The following UCI memorandum shows the dates at which rule 1.3.068 was changed.

I suspect this change was in the 2015 or 2017 revision, but I can't find them online.

https://www.uci.org/docs/default-source/rules-and-regulations-right-column/2018/part-i-general-organisation-of-cycling-as-a-sport-amendments-to-regulations-as-from-22-10-2018.pdf